# Some beans are not woven by AspectJ Load Time Weaving in Spring 5.2.x Web Application

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, javaagents, load-time-weaving

### Application Description

We have Spring (**5.1.11**) web application with XML based spring application context. Project is rather large, we heavily use both component scan and xml description to define beans.
There are several Aspects which provide around advices for the annotated methods. We use AspectJ definition and Load Time Weaving.

Application server - Caucho Resin 4.0.62 (although identical problem and behavior was reproduced on Tomcat 9.0.20).

We do **NOT** use "-javaagent" to apply neither *aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar* not *spring-instrument-5.1.11.RELEASE.jar*.
Aspects were always applied without any problems as according to the documentation if your application server supports (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-aj-ltw-environments):

> You can simply enable load-time weaving, as described earlier.

### Problem Description

Having migrated to Spring **5.2.1** we noticed that **SOME** beans are not woven anymore. After investigation it turned out that beans from *autoscan* do not receive aspect advices anymore.
It looks as if classloader loads these classes too early (before transformer is applied to classloader) and as a result they will not be woven anymore.

As a side effect we noticed that beans defined via annotation config in case they are defined without interface also cannot be woven. Most probably due to the same reason - class is loaded too early. But this problem existed before 5.2.1 (at least on Spring 5.1.11).

In case external javaagent is applied in any version of spring load time weaving works fine, as expected.

### Application to reproduce the problem

Please find here small web application which demonstrates the problem: https://github.com/densp/aspectj-in-spring521

### Questions

1. What is wrong with AspectJ LTW on default classloader without javaagent? It is a problem with Spring 5.2.x or with my configuration? Behaviour has changed!
2. Is it correct behavior to skip weaving for classes without interface in case annotation config?
3. Could you please recommend some workaround? There are too many beans to change their definition and/or make refactoring. External agent on the other side causes much slower startup...

Comment: Define **Having migrated to Spring 5.2.1 ** ... What did you do? Did you stick with XML or also modified to Java based configuration?

Comment: Configuration has not been changed and still XML based (too complex to make changes...). So only dependencies have been changed in pom. 
In my example app the only change one should make to see the difference - change version of spring-boot-starter-parent.

Comment: Then I would suggest to register a bug/issue in the Spring repository, with your sample project.

Comment: Done :)
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24141